# Docker Client server different. And there is no boot2docker

Tags: docker

My machine debian VM. It is not having boot2docker.
Docker was installed in it. I somehow updated docker.It is now giving me error of client and server of not same version.
 by running "docker version" gives me this
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.16, server: 1.15)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have images or containers you wish to keep, remove and install again the latest docker version, with `sudo apt-get remove lxc-docker && sudo apt-get purge lxc-docker && sudo apt-get install lxc-docker`

Comment: I have tried it too. But its not working. And a strange thing is that after removing docker, and before installing it, if i do "docker info", it gives me the same error. I have no idea how docker was installed on this VM.

Comment: docker is removed after `apt-get remove` AND `apt-get purge` not before

Comment: yes. I have executed the following:apt-get remove AND apt-get purge. "docker info". It gives the same error

Comment: that docker is installed, while installing kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is [dvm, the Docker Version Manager](https://github.com/rgbkrk/dvm).

Clone it to, e.g. `~/.dvm`:

```
git clone https://github.com/rgbkrk/dvm.git ~/.dvm
```

Then you need to source it directly or place it in your bash profile:

```
. ~/.dvm/dvm.sh
```

After this, install the version of `docker` you need:

```
$ dvm install 1.6.1
######################################################################## 100.0%
Now using Docker 1.6.1
```

You can swap between versions through `dvm use VERSION`:

```
$ dvm use 1.8.2
Now using Docker 1.8.2
```